# In which thread does block driver issue commands to block device?

Tags: linux-kernel, io, block-device

I'm currently reading "Understanding The Linux Kernel" book, as I've understood block I/O request order is like this; user space call => vfs call => I/O scheduler call => block device driver call.

What I want to know is where the block device driver issue commands to block device (hard disk etc)? Does it issue commands in a dedicated scheduled kernel thread or in the user process thread where the block I/O request begin?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing synchronous IOs, the user doing the write will just create transactions for the kjournald thread to dequeue (note here: I'm using an **ext3** file system with **journal=ordered**, traces given using **Linux 3.0-rc7**)

We can have a look at what is happening by putting a breakpoint on the IO scheduler elevator_dispatch_fn method, for example deadline_dispatch_requests for the deadline IO scheduler:

There are two ways the device queue will run:

either called from the kjournald thread that will run (ext3 file system, mounted with the default commit=5, and is therefore scheduled to run every 5s)

```
#0  deadline_dispatch_requests (q=, force=0) at block/deadline-iosched.c:246
#1  __elv_next_request (q=<optimized out>) at block/blk.h:86
#2  blk_peek_request (q=q@entry=) at block/blk-core.c:1829
#3  scsi_request_fn (q=) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:1511
#4  __blk_run_queue (q=) at block/blk-core.c:305
#5  queue_unplugged (q=, depth=1, from_schedule=<optimized out>) at block/blk-core.c:2673
#6  blk_flush_plug_list (plug=plug@entry=, from_schedule=from_schedule@entry=false) at block/blk-core.c:2755
#7  blk_finish_plug (plug=plug@entry=) at block/blk-core.c:2762
#8  journal_commit_transaction (journal=journal@entry=) at fs/jbd/commit.c:412
#9  kjournald (arg=) at fs/jbd/journal.c:152
#10 kthread (_create=) at kernel/kthread.c:96
#11 kernel_thread_helper () at arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S:1161
#12 ?? ()
```

Either called from an interrupt:

```
#0  deadline_dispatch_requests (q=, force=0) at block/deadline-iosched.c:246
#1  __elv_next_request (q=<optimized out>) at block/blk.h:86
#2  blk_peek_request (q=q@entry=) at block/blk-core.c:1829
#3  scsi_request_fn (q=) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:1511
#4  __blk_run_queue (q=) at block/blk-core.c:305
#5  blk_run_queue (q=q@entry=) at block/blk-core.c:339
#6  scsi_run_queue (q=q@entry=) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:449
#7  scsi_next_command (cmd=cmd@entry=) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:502
#8  scsi_end_request (requeue=<optimized out>, bytes=<optimized out>, error=<optimized out>, cmd=) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:574
#9  scsi_io_completion (cmd=cmd@entry=, good_bytes=<optimized out>) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:822
#10 scsi_finish_command (cmd=cmd@entry=) at drivers/scsi/scsi.c:847
#11 scsi_softirq_done (rq=<optimized out>) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:1456
#12 blk_done_softirq (h=<optimized out>) at block/blk-softirq.c:34
#13 __do_softirq () at kernel/softirq.c:238
#14 call_softirq () at arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S:1210
#15 do_softirq () at arch/x86/kernel/irq_64.c:80
#16 invoke_softirq () at kernel/softirq.c:325
#17 irq_exit () at kernel/softirq.c:340
#18 smp_apic_timer_interrupt (regs=<optimized out>) at arch/x86/kernel/apic/apic.c:862
#19 <signal handler called>
#20 irq_stack_union ()
```

Now if you are doing synchronous calls, the request_fn method will run directly within the write system call, as seen below:

```
#0  deadline_dispatch_requests (q=, force=0) at block/deadline-iosched.c:246
#1  __elv_next_request (q=<optimized out>) at block/blk.h:86
#2  blk_peek_request (q=q@entry=) at block/blk-core.c:1829
#3  scsi_request_fn (q=) at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:1511
#4  __blk_run_queue (q=) at block/blk-core.c:305
#5  queue_unplugged (q=, depth=1, from_schedule=<optimized out>) at block/blk-core.c:2673
#6  blk_flush_plug_list (plug=<optimized out>, from_schedule=from_schedule@entry=false) at block/blk-core.c:2755
#7  blk_flush_plug (tsk=<optimized out>) at include/linux/blkdev.h:880
#8  io_schedule () at kernel/sched.c:5669
#9  sleep_on_page (word=<optimized out>) at mm/filemap.c:182
#10 __wait_on_bit (wq=, q=q@entry=, action=action@entry=<sleep_on_page>, mode=mode@entry=2) at kernel/wait.c:202
#11 wait_on_page_bit (page=page@entry=, bit_nr=bit_nr@entry=13) at mm/filemap.c:571
#12 wait_on_page_writeback (page=) at include/linux/pagemap.h:394
#13 filemap_fdatawait_range (mapping=mapping@entry=, start_byte=start_byte@entry=0, end_byte=end_byte@entry=511) at mm/filemap.c:292
#14 filemap_write_and_wait_range (mapping=, lstart=0, lend=511) at mm/filemap.c:371
#15 filemap_write_and_wait_range (mapping=mapping@entry=, lstart=lstart@entry=0, lend=lend@entry=511) at mm/filemap.c:378
#16 vfs_fsync_range (file=, start=start@entry=0, end=end@entry=511, datasync=0) at fs/sync.c:176
#17 generic_write_sync (file=file@entry=, pos=pos@entry=0, count=count@entry=512) at fs/sync.c:242
#18 generic_file_aio_write (iocb=<optimized out>, iov=, nr_segs=1, pos=<optimized out>) at mm/filemap.c:2614
#19 do_sync_write (filp=, buf=<optimized out>, len=<optimized out>, ppos=) at fs/read_write.c:348
#20 vfs_write (file=file@entry=, buf=buf@entry="", count=<optimized out>, count@entry=512, pos=pos@entry=) at fs/read_write.c:377
#21 sys_write (fd=<optimized out>, buf="", count=512) at fs/read_write.c:429
```

Answer (score 0):

To my current understanding, the user space process asks the system to return I/O. Then, the process will Wait for an interrupt from the kernel that the work is done. User space does not and should not care how the kernel retrieves the data. It might be that vfs found the data somewhere in its cache, so the I/O scheduler is not relevant from the user process.